# Exporting JMeter configuration file to repository

Tags: jmeter

I have read somewhere that it is possible to export JMeter configuration file to a repository e.g.github or bitbucket but I have been unable to find the file.

I can set up JMeter to run and can interpret the results but my aim is to share the configuration file via a repository. I was expecting to find the configuration file in the JMeter `/bin` directory but it doesn't seem to be there. Where else could it be located?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to follow:

1. Sign Up on Github [here](https://github.com/)
2. Create a public or private repository of your choice (by clicking on `New Repository` button). public - all users can access your repository. private - only those users you added,can access the repository. private repositories come with a price tag, where public repositories are free.
3. Once the repository is created, you can upload files from your PC to the repository using `Upload files.` button. select `jmeter.properties` or any config file you want to share.
4. Once all the files are uploaded, commit the changes by giving the summary of what files you are uploading in the text fields and click on `Commit Changes` button. this is just for reference. With this step, you saved your config file in your GitHub account.
5. If it public repository, you can share the URL to the repository to whomever you want. If it is a private repositiory, you can add them as Contributors to the repository, so that they can download/update the files in the repository.

You can download GutHub desktop application to perform operations on the repositories.

---

Why are you preferring GitHub?? A simple way to achieve the task is upload to one of the cloud storage applications like OneDriver, Google Drive, DropBox etc. and share from there.

GitHub is version control tool which is used to maintain the projects (maintains the code version wise), though you can use it for uploading and sharing files.

Comment: thanks for the input. I can see from your response that this is a manual approach to file upload on Github, i.e. uploading directlly from the PC. Similar to the way one can commit projects from an IDE liike eclipse directly to Github, I thought its possible via Jmeter platform to send a file to Github directly. Not sure this is possible but your response was useful, however!

Comment: I can seem to find jmeter.properties. Any idea how to locate this?

Comment: You can upload the file using JMeter. Use HTTP Request File Upload field and provide the file path and URL to whcih you have to upload. You should take care of Cookies and other session relation stuff for that user you logged in. 2. jmeter.properties in inside JMeter/bin directory. As you mentioned, you want to share JMetrer configuration file, I mnetioned jmeter.properties file. You can upload any file that you want.